Google App OAuth Screen triggered by credentials.json references wrong app name
Google Support Basic/Billing Pages advise that Stackoverflow is the go-to for Google Cloud tech help. I have read some questions here on SO that are close to my issue. But none close enough to help.
I have several internal Google apps which have been developed over the last month. Each app has a unique name and is associated with its own project which also has a unique name. But every time I authenticate (Browser launches => "appFoo wants to access your Google Account" etc) The app name reads the same. I should see the current app name. Not an old one.
These apps use a combination of credentials.json & DownloadFileToken.json for the purpose of OAuth. Examining these files for each app shows me that client_id in DownloadFileToken.json remains the same for each app.
In contrast I can see a unique client_id & project_id in the credentials.json file for each app/project
Therefore why is the client_id (app name) in credentials.json not reflected in the app name on the Auth screen? It appears the client_id (app name) from the file DownloadFileToken.json may be what is showing instead.
Being internal apps this could be seen as trivial. But this is a core aspect of authentication and could also affect logging.

It's been awhile since I configured user-based OAuth. You're correct in your assumption that different Client IDs will yield different OAuth dialog prompts. This is because the Client ID and associated Client Secret are different for each app. It's possible for the same Project ID to occur in the credentials because you must issue Client IDs for each app type (web, Android etc.). When you confgiure a Google Project's OAuth consent screen, you could provide the same app name. Is that a possibility?

It's unclear why you have 2 credentials for each app (type). You should have created OAuth Client IDs for each app (type) and, by default, these will be called client_secret_{Client ID}.json. What the 2 credentials that you're using?

I don't know how long it's been for you. But this changed things for me https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/resources/oob-migration So the process I'm using now it to configure a GCP project with OAuth credentials, API key & consent screen for a given project/app name.  The only download at this point is a .json file that I rename credentials.json. Then when I run my .js code an auth screen launches in browser. When I give permission to access my Google account DownloadFileToken.json downloads automatically. I copy this over to repo. All good from here.

I worked at Google looking after enterprise Clouds customer but retired 5 years ago. I think I understand. DownloadFileToken.json is the access|refresh token pair returned by a successful OAuth2 flow. Your persist these for a user to avoid retriggering the full consent flow. I still don't understand how different Client IDs could redirect you to the same consent screen. I trust your experience but it's a bunch of effort to try to create a repro though it would help if you were able to do this.

Yes. I think your description is accurate. It may be a bit obvious. But I have not cleared my browser history since I began doing this. Since the line in the credentials.json is "redirect_uris":["http://localhost" the process may get subverted by the original filename of the original run. I will test this.

Yes. Clearing browsing history fixed the 'problem'. I should have thought of this sooner :-/
